# Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model class Program and created a service class called github.service.ts. When i am creating a variable of type  array of Program and trying to push the element ( a Program object), it is giving compilation error saying "[ts] Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'."

program.model.ts

```
export class Program{

    constructor(public name: string, public url: string){};
}
```

github.service.ts

```
import { Program } from 'src/app/learning/program.model';
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http , Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class GithubService{

    private programList: Program[] = [new Program('test','test')];

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    getPracticeQuestions(){

    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/testuser/practice/contents/')
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const programs: Program[] = response.json();
                for( let program of programs){

                       const res: Program = new Program(program.name, program.url);
                       console.log('res:'+res.name+"::"+res.url);
                       this.programList.push(res);

                }
            }
        );    


    }  
}
```

programList type is showing : (property) GithubService.programList: {}

Comment: probably your `response.json()` is not an array also what version of rxjs are you using? Is the `https://api.github.com/repos/testuser/practice/contents/` true url you are using or should we test some other to find your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need recheck your full source code, somewhere you set it to other object {}

I tried reproduce your source code, it worked normally.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ximbqd

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private programList = new Array<Program>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine , might be error in some response,

Please refer to

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-addinarray

Answer (score -1):

programList: Array= [new Program('test','test')];

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.